# How to show line chart for the given data with legends and labels?

Tags: python, matplotlib, linechart

Data:

```
Taluka_name     Year_2010   Year_2011   Year_2012   Year_2013
AKOLA            7323.9        7665.9      3462     2384.4
AKOT             5471.3        5583.3      972.5    1253.2
BALAPUR          4571.8        4915.6      1961.2   1637.1
BARSHI_TAKALI    4077.4        4203.7      2225.5   1017
MURTIJAPUR       3258.5        3326.5      1463.5   908.5
PATUR            3444.8        3526.3      2340.3   1063.5
TELHARA          4199.1        4287.4      2156.9   1699.4
```

I want to draw a line chart. 
where year is in x axes and y axes will be Taluka_name.

Where in x axes labels show me  "year-2010, year-2011 , year-2012, year-2013" instead of 1 ,2 ,3 ,4

and in y axes  labels show me "AKOLA" , "AKOT", "BALAPUR" ... etc.

And for each taluka_name , line color will be change.

I am using matplotlib .

I have tried this code:  but i dont get label name and different color in lines chart.

Code :

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> data = pd.read_csv('/home/desktop/gram.csv')
>>> data2=data[['Year_2010','Year_2011','Year_2012','Year_2013']]
>>> data1=data['Taluka_name']
>>> fig, ax = plt.subplots()
>>> ax.plot( data2, 'k--', label='Year')
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x7f42a35b5f90>, <matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x7f42a34ecd90>, <matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x7f42a34eced0>, <matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x7f42a34f9050>, <matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x7f42a34f9190>, <matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x7f42a34f92d0>]
>>> legend = ax.legend(loc='upper center', shadow=True, fontsize='x-large')
>>> legend.get_frame().set_facecolor('#00FFCC')
>>> plt.show()
>>>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use pandas plot functionality:

```
In [14]: df
Out[14]: 
     Taluka_name  Year_2010  Year_2011  Year_2012  Year_2013
0          AKOLA     7323.9     7665.9     3462.0     2384.4
1           AKOT     5471.3     5583.3      972.5     1253.2
2        BALAPUR     4571.8     4915.6     1961.2     1637.1
3  BARSHI_TAKALI     4077.4     4203.7     2225.5     1017.0
4     MURTIJAPUR     3258.5     3326.5     1463.5      908.5
5          PATUR     3444.8     3526.3     2340.3     1063.5
6        TELHARA     4199.1     4287.4     2156.9     1699.4

In [15]: df=df.set_index('Taluka_name')

In [16]: df.transpose().plot()
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Are you sure you want the y axis labels to be Taluka names? How would you print a line then?

Comment: ,Thanks  can you give me some idea also  for line pattern ,gives different style like for AKOLA it will be  ( -- ) , for AKOT it will be ( ::: )  ?

Comment: @Seabastian , oh yes you are right, no need to y axis as taluka name

Comment: You said x axis. supply `style=` to the plot method according to this: http://matplotlib.org/examples/lines_bars_and_markers/line_styles_reference.html

Comment: @Seabastian, correct. thanks, it will show me wait 3minutes for accepting answer.